# OCI.dll Error Sqlplus

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

When i tried to connect slqplus,the message is that "OCI.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an error" appeared. Does anybody know this error's solution ?

Comment: So many missing details... What kind of oracle installation did you use? What is your operating system? Have you tried removing and reinstalling?

Comment: My operating system is windows 7 professional. I have to use oracle sql developer and oracle database 11g express edition. now, i try to reinstall

Comment: SQL Developer and SQL\*Plus are separate clients. It would be helpful to edit the question to say exactly what you have installed (link to the download page(s) and say which versions), and exactly what you are trying to run. Also see if any logs are created when the error occurs.

Comment: Are you trying to run a 64bit app on a 32bit operating system?